# Stata Error : Too Many Variables Specified

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, stata

I am creating a frequency bar chart in Stata for a defined list of options. But I got this error on tabulate command "**Too many variables specified**".

- Create a new variable for each response option

```
gen option1 = strpos(question, "Option A") > 0
gen option2 = strpos(question, "Option B") > 0
gen option3 = strpos(question, "Option C") > 0
gen option4 = strpos(question, "Option D") > 0
gen option5 = strpos(question, "Option E) > 0
```

- Calculate the frequency and percentage for each response option

```
tabulate option1 option2 option3 option4 option5, gen(option_count) row format(%12.2f)

graph bar option_count1-option_count5, over(total) asyvars ///
title("Percentage of respondents selecting each option") ///
ylabel(%3.0f) ytitle("Percentage of respondents") ///
legend(order(1 "Option 1" 2 "Option 2" 3 "Option 3" 4 "Option 4" 5 "Option 5"))
```

Comment: The command works with one variable or with two variables. What kind of table were you expecting? A tabulate on your original variable should work fine.

Comment: Or see tabsplit from the tab_chi package on SSC.